# how to solve this pattern in java

Tags: java, for-loop

Input:
3
Output:
3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 $3 3 2 2 1 1 $3 2 1 $

Note : Instead of printing new line print a "$" without quotes.

```
  Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();


    for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
            {

            for(int j=n;j>0;j--)
            {

               System.out.print(i);


            }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use this:

```
void pattern(int n){
   int k,i,j ;
   for( k=n; k>0; k--){        
    for(i=n; i>0; i--){
       for(j=k; j>0 ; j--){
           System.out.print(i);
       }       
    }
   System.out.print("$");      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        doRecursive(n,n);
    }
    in.close();
}

private static void doRecursive(int n, int k) {
    if(n < 1)
        return;
    for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print('$');
    doRecursive(n-1,k);
}
```

Comment: can you explain me what is the value of k?

Comment: k is starting number, n is number of times to print